# support with Jenkins configuration

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I installed Jenkins on my -AWS EC2 Ubuntu- and on the same server I'm running Docker. what I'm trying to do is to build a pipeline via Jenkins on that EC2 Instance. my jenkinsfile stored on Github

When I run the pipeline I get the following error:
Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘docker'
How to solve this problem?

I went to manage Jenkins -> global tools and also to configure system 
but non of these solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: If you use docker in Jenkinsfile and not specify agent, Jenkins will try to find a slave which has docker label as the agent to run docker cmd. Add label `docker` to your slave in `Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes` or somewhere to configure global docker setttings

Comment: It's working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   but now I've got this error:   Error response from daemon: pull access denied for apache, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'  ---- Do I add docker login in my Jenkinsfile or in Jenkins panel ?????